# How to get each json from Promisse.all and then atribute Json properties in setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, fetch, es6-promise

I was working with "fetch" and all was working fine. I got a json file from API and then I passed the result for an object in a setState as below:

```
fetch(
      `https://api.io/api/v1/`, {
       method:'GET',
       headers: { 
              'content-type': 'application/json',
              'x-access-token': 'xxx-xxx-xxx',
                }
    })

  .then(res => res.json())

  .then(json => {

    this.setState({
      index: res.json.result.uv,
      isLoading: false,

      });
  });
```

Now I need to work with diferent results from the API, setting new objects in setState for each one. I've found "Promisse.all" that was able to create an array for my different requests in only one promisse. Unfortunately I did not have sucess trying to get these json files. The code would be like that:

```
Promise.all([
fetch(
      `https://api.io/api/v1/dt=${date1}`, {
       method:'GET',
       headers: { 
              'content-type': 'application/json',
              'x-access-token': 'xxx-xxx-xxx',
                }
    }),
fetch(
      `https://api.io/api/v1/dt=${date2}`, {
       method:'GET',
       headers: { 
              'content-type': 'application/json',
              'x-access-token': 'xxx-xxx-xxx',
                }
    }),
fetch(
      `https://api.io/api/v1/dt=${date3}`, {
       method:'GET',
       headers: { 
              'content-type': 'application/json',
              'x-access-token': 'xxx-xxx-xxx',
                }
    })

  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(json => {

    this.setState({

      index: res[0].json.data,
      index1: res[1].json.data,
      index2: res[2].json.data,

      isLoading: false,
      });
  });
```

In fact I could get a json file from array doing:

```
.then(res => res[0].json())
  .then(json => {

    this.setState({

      index: json.data,
      isLoading: false,
      });
  });
```

But I need more than one object in setState (as above), so it does not work for my project:

Thanks for helping guys!!!

Comment: Did you try adding a .then(res => res.json()) to each fetch in your promise.all array?  Not sure if that would work or not.

Comment: `.then(responses => Promise.all(responses.map(res => res.json())))`

Comment: @BryanEuton I have not tried, but it works !!!!! Thanks man!! Now I just need to make it shorter haha

Answer (score 0):

Could map a dates array into fetch promises and make it all simpler and to make sure you have the `then(res=>res.json()` for each. You seem to be missing that part

```
const dates = [date1, date2, date3]

const promises = dates.map(d => fetch(`https://api.io/api/v1/dt=${d}`, {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'x-access-token': 'xxx-xxx-xxx',
  }
}).then(res => res.json()))

Promises.all(promises).then(res => {
  this.setState({

    index: res[0].json.data,
    index1: res[1].json.data,
    index2: res[2].json.data,

    isLoading: false,
  });
});
```